# Move code file under another file in project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, csproj

I want to move one code file under the group of another, related file, like here:

[image: code file grouping]

As you see, `SingleObjectViewModel.Commands.cs` is hidden in `SingleObjectViewModel.cs` group. It can be useful in some cases.

I've created `SingleDocumentViewModel.Commands.cs` but simple drag-n-drop in Visual Studio do not work.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one way of doing this, but it is not user-friendly and needs to edit project file by hands. I'm not sure it will work in other versions of Visual Studio then mine (MS Visual Studio 2013)

First, unload project (right-click on project, `Unload Project`).

Then edit `csproj` file (right-click again, `Edit *.csproj`)

In editor, replace:

```
<Compile Include="SingleDocumentViewModel.Commands.cs">
```

with

```
<Compile Include="SingleDocumentViewModel.Commands.cs">
  <DependentUpon>SingleDocumentViewModel.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Then save edited file and load project again (right-click on it, `Reload project`).

Now files are grouped:

[image: grouped files]