# Add additional appsettings.Environment.json under the appsettings.json file

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.2

When I am creating a new ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio, it creates for me some **appsettings.json** and also **appsettings.Development.json**. They look like below:

[image]

If I am adding these files in a regular .Net Core Console Application project, they will be added at the same level and I won't have the possibility to move the environment specific settings under the general **appsettings.json** file.

[image]

I have checked the .csproj files and I don't see any mention of these files in any of them.

My question is how can I make **appsettings.Development.json** stay within **appsettings.json** in this tree like structure as in the ASP.NET Core project in other .NET Core projects.

Comment: They don't need to. How they are organized in the solution explorer is purely visual thing.

Comment: @fredrik isn't there any setting, that I can do and version it?

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to edit the csproj-file manually. And it's completely unnecessary because it makes no difference whatsoever when the application is executed.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397824/move-code-file-under-another-file-in-project) is not for .NET Core - but it should be similair.

Comment: @fredrik okay, this is what the question is targeting, that modification of .csproj file. If I remember correctly, in .Net Framework there were some changes that I could be making to the csproj file to display them in this structure, but in .Net Core I can't find these changes that I need to make.

Comment: @fredrik thanks a lot, it seems to be working for .Net Core projects also!

Comment: @fredrik post that as an answer.

Comment: @IanKemp I closed this as being a duplicate, as it currently is, and upvoted the other question and answer because they are helpful.